# Android Studio Vector Asset "Clip Art" button doesn't work. How can i fix it?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

i clicked that red lined button but nothing showed up.

restart Android Studio but still doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed the issue:
File > Repair IDE